# WebApi OData only able to POST and GET entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have created a simple CRUD application using WebApi OData. I have been using the Composer tab of Fiddler 2 to test the service and no matter what I do I keep getting an HTTP 404 reponse from my local IIS server. As stated a **POST** request works:

> `http://mymachine/Service.Facade.Reports/odata/Reports`
>
> User-Agent: Fiddler
>
> Content-Type: application/json
>
> Host: localhost
>
> Content-Length: 1373
>
> {
>     "Name":"Report...","Group":"Hhowd444","ReportLayoutID":8270,"DatabaseInstanceID":1042
>   }

So I tried:

> However, changing the URL to: >
>   `http://mymachine/Service.Facade.Reports/odata/Reports(8270)` and
>   executing a **PUT** does not work

The PUT leads to a 404 error. My attempts to debug and trace the service have led nowhere.

In the WebApiConfig class:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<ReportLayout>("Reports");
    builder.EntitySet<ReportLayoutData>("ReportLayoutData");
    builder.EntitySet<DatabaseInstance>("DataSources");
    builder.EntitySet<DataSourceObject>("DataSourceObject");

    config.Routes.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());

    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{key}",
        defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

The Post and Put from the controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(ReportLayout reportlayout)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.Reports.Add(reportlayout);
    db.ReportsData.AddRange(reportlayout.LayoutData);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Created(reportlayout);
}

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] int key, ReportLayout reportlayout)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (key != reportlayout.ReportLayoutID)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    db.Entry(reportlayout).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        if (!ReportLayoutExists(key))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return Updated(reportlayout);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the code was not the issue but the configuration of my IIS 7.5 server.

To resolve go to:

1. IIS Manager
2. Handler Mappings
3. Find the ExpresslessUrlHandler...entries x 3
4. Right click, edit
5. Select Request Restrictions
6. Hit the Verbs tab
7. Either add the extra verbs or just select All Verbs

Everything works now after some pain and suffering!